# Google Chrome - Mouse Not Changing

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, mouse, opera, webkit

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (not in a VirtualBox) with Chrome, and I have a interesting issue. Currently there is a solution to a similar problem listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593274/google-chrome-cursor-and-text-selection-issues-after-upgrading-to-google-chrome) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3Kvz9eGm87M), but my problem is just slightly different and none of the known fixes for the other problem are working.

My problem is that the mouse does not change when placed over things such as links where the mouse should turn into a pointing hand, or over text where there should be the I beam. Also, hover states and active states on website elements aren't being triggered either. However, if I'm currently scrolling or the mouse is held down, then everything works fine, but not while only moving the mouse.

I have tried:

- Purge and reinstall of Chrome
- Running Chrome with `--touch-devices=123`
- Trying to recreate this error on another system (Without success)
- Trying Opera (since it's also WebKit, which has the same issue)

**NOTE:** The other more widely seen bug has symptoms that aren't affecting me. For example, my scrolling and text selection is working completely fine.

Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)

UA Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome

Comment: happens on chromium too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of bug reports about this problem.

[Issue 465660: Cursor functionality broken in Ubuntu 14.04 since 41](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465660)
is perhaps the most promising. Its last entry says :

> version 43 works fine, just install google-chrome-unstable

[Issue 357347: Mouse cursor stopped turning into a pointer while hovering over links](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357347) has several workarounds that may not pertain to your problem :

- disable Chrome hardware acceleration
- disabling Synergy server
- this happens with Photoshop CC 2014 in the background (the window is open, just behind Chrome). Hiding Photoshop solves the issue.

Comment: This is the first entry I have seen about Synergy, which is the only difference between any of my other computers and this one. I will try this when I get to work tomorrow and check if Synergy is causing the problem.

Comment: Yup, Synergy server was the problem here, that's too bad, but at least now I know where to start looking for workarounds and fixes. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and found some "nightly builds" on the Synergy website that may also be helpful to others.

I'm currently using:

```
Google Chrome v46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)
Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64-bit)
Gnome Session Flashback (compiz)
```

and now, **Synergy 1.8.0-alpha-19835b6** on both machines.

I downloaded [this](https://synergy-project.org/files/nightly/synergy-master-alpha-19835b6-Linux-x86_64.deb) "nightly build" from [here](https://synergy-project.org/nightly?hl=es) and worked like a charm. No need to restart the browser or anything.